# Rspec method missing for stub_chain with Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, stub

I am attempting to use `stub_chain` to mock a series of calls in a controller action. However it is complaining about a method not found error. After a bunch of searching, I didn't really find any info relating to this specific error, so I figure I am missing something fairly obvious. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Here is the error:

```
Admin::AccountsController GET #index with accounts 
 Failure/Error: before(:each) { Account.stub_chain(:scoped, :page, :order).returns([account]) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `stub_chain' for #<Class:0x007f96c6448158>
 # ./spec/controllers/admin/accounts_controller_spec.rb:11:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Source for the spec:

```
#spec/controllers/admin/accounts_controller.rb
describe 'GET #index' do

  context 'with accounts' do

    let(:account) { FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:account) }
    before(:each) { Account.stub_chain(:scoped, :page, :order).returns([account]) }

    subject { get :index }

    it { should render_template(:index) }
    it { should assign_to(:accounts) }
    it { should respond_with(:success) }
    it { should_not set_the_flash }
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you missing `require "spec_helper"`?

Comment: @zetetic No, the require is there. If i remove the before statement a few of the specs pass.

Comment: What version of RSpec?

Comment: Also, I doubt it makes a difference, but normally the spec file would be named `accounts_controller_spec.rb`.

Comment: @zetetic it is version 2.12.0, also the file name is a type in the comment.